Setting up Tone.js on button click still fails with : The AudioContext was not allowed to start
I have a angular component that has a button to start an animation and at the same time play some notes each time a number is highlighted

I'm setting up tone.js synth when the button is pressed see escalaPentatonicaToggle but I'm still getting an error about The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page
Why am I getting that error even when the sound is trying to be played after a CLICK event ? how can I solve it.
I have seen this similar question but offers a different scenario
Tone.js - The AudioContext was not allowed to start
Here is the component logic

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ElementoPentatonica, EscalaPentatonica, NotasEscalaPentatonica } from '../../models/EscalaPentatonica';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ElementoPentatonicaComponent } from '../elemento-pentatonica/elemento-pentatonica.component';
import * as Tone from 'tone';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-escala-pentatonica',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ElementoPentatonicaComponent],
  templateUrl: './escala-pentatonica.component.html',
  styleUrl: './escala-pentatonica.component.css'
})
export class EscalaPentatonicaComponent {
  escala: EscalaPentatonica;
  highlightedIndex: number = 0;
  timer: any;
  lapse: number = 600;
  running: boolean = false;
  soundEnabled: boolean = true;
  sonido = "LA";
  start = 1;
  lineasFlat: ElementoPentatonica[] = [];
  synth: Tone.Synth | null = null;

  constructor() {
    this.escala = new EscalaPentatonica(this.start, NotasEscalaPentatonica.SI_MAYOR, this.sonido);
    this.lineasFlat = this.escala.lineas.flat();
  }

  onSelectionChange(event: Event) {
    this.stopAnimation();

    this.start = Number((event.target as HTMLSelectElement).value);
    this.escala = new EscalaPentatonica(this.start, NotasEscalaPentatonica.SI_MAYOR, this.sonido);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  async escalaPentatonicaToggle() {
    await Tone.start();

    if (!this.running) {
      await this.startAnimation();
    } else {
      this.stopAnimation();
    }
    this.running = !this.running;
  }

  async startAnimation() {
    this.synth = new Tone.Synth().toDestination();
    this.highlightedIndex = 0;
    this.startTimer();
  }

  stopAnimation() {
    if (this.timer) {
      clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
    if (this.synth) {
      this.synth.dispose();
      this.synth = null;
    }
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.stopAnimation();
  }

  startTimer() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.highlightedIndex = (this.highlightedIndex + 1) % this.lineasFlat.length;
      this.playSound(this.highlightedIndex);
    }, this.lapse);
  }

  getIndex(i: number, j: number): number {
    let index = 0;
    for (let x = 0; x < i; x++) {
      index += this.escala.lineas[x].length;
    }
    return index + j;
  }

  playSound(index: number) {
    let note = this.escala.notas[this.lineasFlat[index].numero - this.escala.start];

    if (this.synth) {
      console.log('Playing note:', note);
      this.synth.triggerAttackRelease(note, '2s');
    }
  }
}

and here is the html
<div class="escala-container">
    <select #escalaSelect (change)="onSelectionChange($event)">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <button class="nextButton" (click)="escalaPentatonicaToggle()">
        {{ running ? 'DETENER' : 'INICIAR' }}
    </button>
    <div *ngFor="let linea of escala.lineas; let i = index" class="linea" [style.margin-left.px]="(4 - i) * 20">
        <app-elemento-pentatonica *ngFor="let elemento of linea; let j = index" [numero]="elemento.numero"
            [sonido]="elemento.sonido" [highlight]="highlightedIndex === getIndex(i, j)">
        </app-elemento-pentatonica>
    </div>
</div>


issue in not reproducible stackblitz please replicate it here and share  back!

I'm trying to replicate it on stackblitz, but you can see the published code here - https://ejercitavoz.netlify.app/escala-pentatonica as soon as you open that page you get the errors that I have mention, it seems like Tone.js is trying to initilize the audio context even before is used

I have tried using stackblitz but I dont have enough knowledge to replicate the code  in there, I could share the code respository and you could take a look; I have actually created a soundService but issue is the same - if works on Firefox Windows, Chorme on Android, Safari but not on Chome Windows

please share the github repo

This is funny and embarressing, for some st*pid reason the tab was muted, it works on chrome, haha

Can you post it a an answer?

Problem solved, reason "The tab was muted". Yes is embarresing ;-)
Also the messages in the console are WARNINGS not errors, and the sound plays just fine.
